# JS Show / hide header on scroll effect - but only after the header has scrolled up and out of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some simple Javascript. When scrolling down the header disappears. When scrolling up the header appears. This all works fine:

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.querySelector("header").style.top = "0";
  } else {
     document.querySelector("header").style.top = "-7.2rem";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}




header {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 7.2rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

However, when the page is at the top of the window, and the user scrolls down, even by 1px, the header disappears, leaving a great big blank space where the header used to be. Is it possible that this show / hide on scroll script only starts once the header has disappeared off the top of the browser window? i.e. the effect only kicks in after the height of the header has been scrolled (so that the user doesn't see the empty white space) i.e. the header is not fixed, but relative. It scrolls up and out of the window. Then the effect starts: scroll down = no header / scroll up = header is fixed at the top of the window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can do this, depending on what behaviour you would like. In both cases we want to get the header element and it's position:

```
var headerDiv = document.querySelector("header");
var headerBottom = headerDiv.offsetTop + headerDiv.offsetHeight;
```

This means that in the scroll, we can check if we have passed the header:

```
    if (window.pageYOffset >= headerBottom)
```

### 1: Header scrolls out of view as normal, Fixed to top on scrolling up

In this version, the header scrolls out of view when scrolling down, but when you start to scroll up it will appear fixed to the top of the screen.

**Full Working Example:**

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

/* Get the header element and it's position */
var headerDiv = document.querySelector("header");
var headerBottom = headerDiv.offsetTop + headerDiv.offsetHeight;

window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;

  /* if scrolling down, let it scroll out of view as normal */
  if (prevScrollpos <= currentScrollPos ){
      headerDiv.classList.remove("fixedToTop");
      headerDiv.style.top ="-7.2rem";
  }
  /* otherwise if we're scrolling up, fix the nav to the top */
  else{  
      headerDiv.classList.add("fixedToTop");
      headerDiv.style.top = "0";
  }

  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
body{ margin: 0;}
header {
    background: blue;
    height: 7.2rem;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}

.content { 
    height:1000px; 
}

header.fixedToTop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

/* add space for fixed header when it's fixed to top */
header.fixedToTop + .content{
    margin-top:8rem;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="content" id="contentdiv">
<h1>My Page</h1>
<p>Content 1</p><p>Content 2</p><p>Content 3</p><p>Content 4</p><p>Content 5</p>
<p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
</div>
```

**How This Works**

We need to remove the fixed positioning from the header and add it to a class (e.g. `fixedToTop`) that we will apply on scrolling:

```
header {
    height: 7.2rem;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}
header.fixedToTop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
```

**Now the logic for our scroll function is very simple:**

1. If we're scrolling down then let the header scroll out of view - remove the `fixedToTop` class.
2. If we are scrolling up, add our `fixedToTop` class which will make it appear

Note, we need to explicitly set the value for `top` to make the transition animation to work, so we do that in the code also.

Putting this together, we get the following scroll function:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;

  /* if scrolling down, let it scroll out of view as normal */
  if (prevScrollpos <= currentScrollPos ){
      headerDiv.classList.remove("fixedToTop");
      headerDiv.style.top ="-7.2rem";
  }
  /* otherwise if we're scrolling up, fix the nav to the top */
  else{  
      headerDiv.classList.add("fixedToTop");
      headerDiv.style.top = "0";
  }

  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

### 2: Header is fixed until we scroll passed where it would normally have disappeared; Fixed to top on on scrolling up

In this case the header is fixed until we scroll passed it's "natural" position where it would disappear.

**Working Example:**

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;

/* Get the header element and it's position */
var headerDiv = document.querySelector("header");
var headerBottom = headerDiv.offsetTop + headerDiv.offsetHeight;

window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;

  /* if we're scrolling up, or we haven't passed the header,
     show the header at the top */
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos  || currentScrollPos < headerBottom){  
      headerDiv.style.top = "0";
  }
  else{
      /* otherwise we're scrolling down & have passed the header so hide it */
      headerDiv.style.top = "-7.2rem";
  } 

  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
header {
    background: blue;
    height: 7.2rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}

.content { 
    height:1000px; 
    margin-top:8rem; /* add space for fixed header */
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="content" id="contentdiv">
<h1>My Page</h1>
<p>Content 1</p><p>Content 2</p><p>Content 3</p><p>Content 4</p><p>Content 5</p>
<p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
<p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p><p>Content</p>
</div>
```

**How This Works**

The logic in your scroll function is like this:

1. If we're scrolling up, then show the header:
2. If we are scrolling down...
3. ...if we've scrolled passed the header, hide it
4. ... otherwise show it

Putting this together, we get the following scroll function:

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset; // save the current position

window.onscroll = function() {
   var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;

  /* if we're scrolling up, or we haven't passed the header, show the header */
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos  || currentScrollPos < headerBottom){  
      headerDiv.style.top = "0";
  }
  else{
      /* otherwise we're scrolling down & have passed the header so hide it */
      headerDiv.style.top = "-7.2rem";
  } 

  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. One question: in JavaScript is it possible to use 'rem' measurements? I thought it had to be pixels?

Comment: We are not actually using the rem value in js here - we are setting the value of the CSS style and it is the CSS that will be used in, so in this case it's fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can just compare the scroll position with the height of the element:

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
   var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
   if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
     document.querySelector("header").style.top = "0";
   } else if (currentScrollPos > document.querySelector("header").offsetHeight) {
     document.querySelector("header").style.top = "-7.2rem";
   }
   prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}

header {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    height: 7.2rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the first answer provided by FluffyKitten and it worked well. Thank you. I would have commented there, but I lack the reputation to do so.

To help others, while implementing FluffyKitten's  first answer, I learned that the vertical alignment of the header and .content varied slightly between (a) load or refresh (no scrolling yet on page so not fixedToTop) versus (b) fixedToTop after scrolling because only the body margins were set to 0.

I not only set the body element margin to 0 (as FluffyKitten does), but also had to set the top margin on the header and on the .content element to 0 to prevent minor vertical layout discrepancies between when my webpages were first loaded or refreshed (when header is not fixedToTop) versus when the header is fixedToTop after scrolling up.

Answer (score 0):

```
export function Header() {

const [prevScrollPos, setPrevScrollPos] = useState(0);

const [headerFixed, setHeaderFixed] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const handleScroll = () => {
    const currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;

    if (currentScrollPos < 100) {
      console.log(currentScrollPos);
      setHeaderFixed(false);
    } else if (prevScrollPos <= currentScrollPos) {
      setHeaderFixed(false);
    } else {
      setHeaderFixed(true);
    }

    setPrevScrollPos(currentScrollPos);
  };

  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  };
}, [prevScrollPos]);

return
   <header className={`sticky transition-all duration-300 z-50 ${headerFixed
       ? " top-0 left-0 right-0 bg-white shadow-md"
       : "bg-transparent"}`}>
     <div>hjasdkjas</div>
   </header>
```

Comment: you can use this code if you are coding with reactjs/nextjs and styling with tailwind